# Noctua CPU Cooler - replacing just the fan

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, cpu-cooler

I have a [Noctua CPU Cooler [NH-U12S]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C9EYVGY), and unfortunately I frayed some wires on just the fan part.

Upon searching for a replacement, I'm only seeing options to re-purchase the entire heatsink, and not just the fan.

But I assume other fans would work, like [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835608053&cm_re=NF-F12-_-35-608-053-_-Product) ? Or, if not, what is the best way to acquire one without having to invest in another heatsink?

Comment: noctura sells all the fans seperately, if you look around. Just pay close attention to the RPMs as they vary from slow&quiet to 3000rpm type and a heatsink (original) may come with one that maxes out at 1500 (rather quiet). If your motherboard offers PWM thermal control 4pin for the cpu fan header (most do) then the 2000rpm would work fine. If you dont have control, only then would you have to worry about the max RPM.

Answer (score 2):

That quite literally is a standard fan according to to the amazon listing - in this case a model PF-N12- probably [one of these, or its 3 pin non PWM varient](http://noctua.at/en/nf-f12-pwm.html). *Any* 120mm fan should work. Just buy one with the same number of pins as your header.